# Dependency property: how to design

Tags: wpf, c#-3.0, wpf-controls, dependency-properties

I have 2 custom controls that are independent of each other in a wpf application.
However, I have some behavior that needs to replicated in both the controls that is similar.

For example, when a user does drag drop on either of these 2 controls, i need more or less the same behavior to execute.

The same behavior also consists of a dependency property that needs to be shared across the 2 controls.

Is this possible and if so how would one go about designing it?

So basically, how do I share a dependency property across controls, and also share some behavior as well, when the controls are independent of each other?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could inherit those 2 controls from a your custom base control that has the dragging logic that you need in both of them. Just like `ListBox` and `ComboBox` derive from `ItemsControl`. That way, they share the same properties and behavior.

If these two controls cannot inherit from the same control, you could implement a common interface just like `ICommandSource` that is implemented by a lot of controls.

Answer (score 0):

Use inheritance - create a common base control containing the logic you need to be the same in both controls and then in their XAML use something like this:

```
<local:BaseClassName
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespaceName"  
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="ChildControlClassName"
x:Name="ChildControlName"
d:DesignWidth="640" 
d:DesignHeight="480" 
>
    ...control XAML
</local:BaseClassName>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use Attached DependencyProperties. Declare your properties on a third class - here is an example of how you could handle DoubleClicking (should be much the same logic) - makes it much easier to re-use without tightly coupling the two controls - especially if one is a Panel and the other an ItemsControl: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42111/Selector-DoubleClick-Behaviour-calling-ViewModel-I.aspx